How to set base_link in r_l
The setup
I have a towed auv which has some sensory onboard. Namely a pressure sensor (for depth measuring), a DVL ( for position, orientation, velocities, GPS) and an altimeter including AHRS (distance to ground and roll pitch heading).
The Question
Id like to fuse the measurements using the robot_localization package. I setup the messages (sensor_msgs::IMU, poseWithCovarinance, twist, naavsat, etc.). I also understand the frame types, but I'm not sure how to set the base_link in the ekf config. I would define the base_link as for example the CoG of the auv, and define static transforms for the sensory frames (offset translatory and rotatory). Do I need to publish a tf for the base_link?
Also if I do not explicitly set a base_link tf, can I instead use the odom frame as base_link?
Code
The launchfile is not complete (at the moment).
from launch import LaunchDescription
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
import launch_ros.actions
import os
import yaml
from launch.substitutions import EnvironmentVariable
import pathlib
import launch.actions
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch_ros.actions import Node


def generate_launch_description():

    tf_depth_keller = Node(package = "tf2_ros",
                       executable = "static_transform_publisher",
                       arguments = ["-0.11", "0",  "0", "0", "0", "0", "odom", "companion_0/pose_keller"])
    tf_depth_dvl = Node(package = "tf2_ros", 
                    executable = "static_transform_publisher",
                    arguments = ["-0.75", "0", "0.15", "0", "0", "0", "odom", "companion_0/dvl/pose"])
    tf_imu_alti = Node(package = "tf2_ros",
                   executable = "static_transform_publisher",
                   arguments = ["0.25", "0", "0", "0", "0,296706", "0", "main_companion_link", "companion_0/alti/imu"])
    tf_imu_dvl = Node(package = "tf2_ros",
                  executable = "static_transform_publisher",
                  arguments = ["-0.75", "0", "0.15", "0", "0", "0", "main_companion_link", "companion_0/dvl/imu"])
    tf_twist_dvl = Node(package = "tf2_ros",
                    executable = "static_transform_publisher",
                    arguments = [])

    return LaunchDescription([
        launch_ros.actions.Node(
            package='robot_localization',
            executable='ekf_node',
            name='ekf_filter_node',
            output='screen',
            parameters=[os.path.join(get_package_share_directory("robot_localization"), 'params', 'ekf.yaml')],
           ),])

and the config file:
### ekf config file ###
ekf_filter_node:
ros__parameters:
    
    frequency: 30.0
    sensor_timeout: 2.0
    two_d_mode: false
    print_diagnostics: true

    smooth_lagged_data: true
    debug: false
    publish_tf: true
    map_frame: map              # Defaults to "map" if unspecified
    odom_frame: odom            # Defaults to "odom" if unspecified
    base_link_frame: main_companion_link  # Defaults to "base_link" if unspecified
    world_frame: odom           # Defaults to the value of odom_frame if unspecified
    pose0: companion_0/dvl/pose
    pose0_config: [true, true, true,
                   false, false, false,
                   false, false, false,
                   false, false, false,
                   false, false, false]
    pose0_differential: false
    pose0_relative: false
    pose0_queue_size: 5

    pose1: companion_0/keller/pose
    pose1_config: [false,  false,  true,
                   false, false, false,
                   false, false, false,
                   false, false, false,
                   false, false, false]
    pose1_differential: false
    pose1_relative: false
    pose1_queue_size: 5


    twist0: companion_0/dvl/twist
    twist0_config: [false, false, false,
                    false, false, false,
                    true,  true,  true,
                    false, false, false,
                    false, false, false]
    twist0_queue_size: 2

    imu0: companion_0/dvl/imu
    imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                  true,  true,  true,
                  false, false, false,
                  true,  true,  true,
                  false,  false,  false]
    imu0_differential: false
    imu0_relative: false
    imu0_queue_size: 5

    imu1: companion_0/isa500/imu
    imu1_config: [false, false, false,
                  true, true, true,
                  false, false, false,
                  false, false, false,
                  false, false, false]
    imu1_differential: false
    imu1_relative: false
    imu1_queue_size: 5
    acceleration_limits: [3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0]
    deceleration_limits: [3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0]
    acceleration_gains: [3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0]
    deceleration_gains: [3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0]
    process_noise_covariance: [0.05, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.05, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.06, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.03, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.03, 0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.06, 0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.025, 0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.025, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.04, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.01, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.01, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.02, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.01, 0.0,    0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.01, 0.0,
                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
    reset_on_time_jump: true
    initial_estimate_covariance: [1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9]


base_link should be the frame for which you want to get a state estimate, typically the base frame of your robot. It is classically defined in the URDF, with fixed transforms (e.g. joints) to the other frames, where sensors are attached.
If you define the model as a URDF the robot_state_publisher will take care of publishing the relevant tf inside your robot. Or you can do that with static transforms as in your launch file, except there is no reason the transform from odom to any sensor is constant.
odom is a totally different frame, it is the one corresponding to the initial pose of the robot and the transform odom -> base_link typically comes from the odometry.
In your configuration file I see your DVL is outputting a pose. If it is just the integration of the corresponding twist then the covariance will grow infinitely and there is not much interest in using it in the filter.

is it necessary to use urdf in combination with the r_l package? means would it cause trouble to leave the base_link_frame as the default ("base_link"). I ask this because i dont need a urdf model to be shown in rviz. If there is no way without a urdf model i will find a way to create one. Also thanks for the advice regarding the pose, i only  need the twist and the z value in pose since its not an integrated value

Well in your case it seems that main_companion_link is the equivalent to a base_link. But the DVL should be placed (with static transform) relative to this link as well, not relative to odom.
